# SQL - find the duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from table1 where destination in  ('chi','usa','ind')
```

Ideally my result set should be 3 rows. one row for each destination.

But in my result there are duplicates.

```
chi
usa
ind
usa
```

I want to find which destination is duplicated.
I have hundreds of destination and i want to delete the duplicate records.
I am not looking for distinct. Am looking for the duplicated ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use group by and having instead of distinct

```
select destination from table1 
where destination in  ('chi','usa','ind')
group by destination 
having count(*)>1
```

If you want to delete these and retain one, it gets a little messy.  This is probably the shortest way, but its a bit of a hack.

```
delete from destination where id not in (
    select max(id) from table1
      where destination in  ('chi','usa','ind')
      group by destination 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a count of duplicates, ordered by number of dupes desc:

```
SELECT CountryAbbr,
       COUNT(*) AS DuplicateCount
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY CountryAbbr
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
Order By 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add group by at the end ... should give you two columns,  on is the country, the other is how many times it was in the list.

So ..

```
select * from table1 where destination in  ('chi','usa','ind') group by destination
```

Hope this helps